# Why do I need z-index in this case?

Tags: css, position, overflow, z-index

I want to make a div (with fixed position) become hidden outside a specified area. This do exactly what I what:

```
<div id="div1" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;">
     <div id="div2" style="position:relative; z-index:10;">
          <div id="div3" style="position:fixed"> </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/wS5Rx/2/) (Firefox only)

But I dont understand why `#div2` needs the `z-index` property?

Also, iirc, my example used to work on Chrome, but not now. Why?

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Vucko I added a jsfiddle, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that div2 has a greater z-index than div3 which will cause parts of DIV3 to not overlap or show through div2/ div1

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wS5Rx/4/

The fixed element is not affected by overflow at all so what you would need to do is to add some JS to make it disappear once the scroll is reached

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#div3').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }else{
        $('#div3').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });        
    }

});
```

Comment: not what I want, I added a jsfiddle, please have a look, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I probably did not get your issue first time, see if this solution helps

Comment: thanks, but my jsfiddle is exactly what I want (doesn't need JS), the problem is that I can't understand why and how it works?